# Comparison between central logic or distributed logic in microservices?

Tags: design, microservices

I'm designing an application in a microservices architecture. The app has its own logic but also needs to collaborate with other services.

For example, the app is A, and other apps are B and C. Whenever there's an event "X" happens in A, The B and C also need to do something like sth-B(), sth-C().

There are two ways that I can think of:

1. Keep the logic in A. So A will know all the things to do when event "X" happens. It will `do sth-A(), then call restful sth-B() and sth-C()`. B and C are simply passive.
2. Distribute logic to B and C. So A will only `do sth-A() and publish the event "X" into a message queue`. B and C will subscribe the event and `do sth-B()` and `do sth-C()` respectively. In this way, **A** doesn't need to care about what subscribers do, but it's hard to know what in the whole system are really being done when the event happens.

My questions are 1) are the above two design ways common? Do they have formal names? 2) Which one should I choose in a microservices architecture?

Comment: Is there any relation between the actions, besides that they are triggered by the same event? For example, might `sth-B` need information calculated in `sth-A`? How bad is it if one of the services is temporarily unavailable and processes the event much later than the others? The answers to these kinds of questions can help in determining how the microservices should interact (or not) with each other.

Comment: Thanks @BartvanIngenSchenau for raising the important questions! Let's simplify the scenario, and assume the actions are independent.